# SSpeechRecognizer delegate to be called for any word spoke

Tags: cocoa, speech-recognition, voice

I read about NSSpeechRecognizer and found that it can recognize a set of commands beings associated with it in delegate: -speechRecognizer:didRecognizeCommand:
I have a simple question: can this delegate be called for any word spoken by user?? as I think.. only a finite number of words can be associated with it!

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what it says on the tin: It's for recognizing commands. So, yes, you need to tell it up front what commands it should recognize.

It's not a dictation API. I would guess that if you tried to load up the command list with an English dictionary, you'd make recognition very processor-intensive, slow, and inaccurate.

If you want dictation, you should [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to ask for it.